# Generic Service Interface

Tags: wcf

I have a Generic Service Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService<T> where T : Class1
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork(T class1);
}
```

Then I have a Concrete Service that inherits from that:

```
public class Service : IService<Class1>
{
    public void DoWork(Class1 class1)
    {
    }
}
```

Everything works fine until I add a webHttpEndpoint to expose a JSON WS:

```
<service name="Service">
    <endpoint 
        address="" 
        binding="webHttpBinding" 
        behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
        contract="IService"  />
</service>

<behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
    <enableWebScript />
</behavior>
```

In fact, I receive this error:

> The contract name 'IService' could not
>   be found in the list of contracts
>   implemented by the service 'Service'.

That's beacuse of the generic definition of the interface.
Any solution?

Comment: Well, your `Service` **doesn't** implement `IService` (as the error clearly says) - it implements `IService<Class1>` - that's a different interface....

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I set that in my web.config?

Comment: You can try to use `contract="IService<Class1>"` but I am afraid this won't work. WCF is not really well suited to generics.....

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does not work.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion (and based on what you said), the interface does not need to be generic. The caller just need to know that there is a DoWork operation.

So basically, change the concrete class to be generic instead of the interface.

```
public class Service<T> : IService where T : Class1
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }
}
```

EDIT after clarifying the question: You need to provide the generic parameter in the config file as well:

```
contract="YourAssembly.IService`1[[YourAssembly.Class1, YourAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"
```

Here is a similar question: [Inheriting from a generic contract in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903977/inheriting-from-a-generic-contract-in-wcf)

Comment: Thanks again. My contract looks like this now: contract="WebApplication1.IService`1[[WebApplication1.Class1, WebApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]" but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You must correctly write the type name of your contract into configuration. `IService` is not the name of `IService<Class1>`!!!

The configuration should look like:

```
<service name="Service">
    <endpoint 
        address="" 
        binding="webHttpBinding" 
        behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
        contract="IService`1[Class1]"  />
</service>

<behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
    <enableWebScript />
</behavior>
```

Be aware that if your contract or service lives in any namespace, namespaces should be included in configuration.

Or in case of full names needed:

```
<service name="Namespace.Service, AssemblyName">
    <endpoint 
        address="" 
        binding="webHttpBinding" 
        behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
        contract="Namespace.IService`1[[Namespace.Class1, AssemblyName]], AssemblyName"  />
</service>

<behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
    <enableWebScript />
</behavior>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Same error. Can you give me a real example?

Comment: The full type name also did not work for me, still WCF cannot find the contract.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your Class1.....Instead of specifying any specific class make it a reference type using `class`

Try something this...

```
 [ServiceContract]public interface IService<T> where T : class
    { 
       [OperationContract] 
       void DoWork();
    }
```