# Contract with generic type in wcf c#

Tags: c#, wcf

I create a service in wcf with this contract :

```
namespace CMSManagement.Domain.Repository
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity:class
    {

        [OperationContract]
        TEntity FindById(Guid id);

        [OperationContract]
        bool Add(TEntity entity);

        [OperationContract]
        bool Remove(TEntity entity);

        [OperationContract]
        bool Edit(TEntity entity);

        [OperationContract]
        bool Save();

        [OperationContract]
        IQueryable<TEntity> Get();

    }
}
```

I want to add this to webconfig :
[image]

```
 <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
                  contract="CMSManagement.Domain.Repository.IRepository"/>
```

But the webconfig can't find this interface why ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code in case of generic interface

```
<service name="Namespace.Service, AssemblyName">
    <endpoint 
        address="" 
        binding="webHttpBinding" 
        behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
        contract="Namespace.IService`1[[Namespace.Class1, AssemblyName]], AssemblyName"  />
</service>

<behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
    <enableWebScript />
</behavior>
```

Possibly the same question at [GenericInterfaceWCF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6224418/1716709)

Comment: contract="CMSManagement.Domain.Repository.IRepository`1[[CMSManagement.Domain.Entity.FileManagement, CMSManagement.Domain]], CMSManagement.Domain"  />---But same problem

Comment: try like mscorlib, contract="CMSManagement.Domain.Repository.IRepository`1[[CMS‌​Management.Domain.En‌​tity.FileManagement]], mscorlib"  />

Comment: it should work, https://weblogs.asp.net/zareian/how-to-write-a-generic-service-in-wcf